# "The coast can expect thunderstorms". What does "expect" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in my textbook: "The coast can expect thunderstorms"

Does the word 'expect' mean we 'hope' something happens in that case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Expect* doesn't mean *hope*.

The sentence your textbook used means "It is expected that the coast will get thunderstorms." which is different from "Her parents expected high standards from her." In the first case, *expected* means *thought* or *believed*; in the second case, *expected* means *demanded*.

Comment: The first example is fine, but in the second, "expected" does not mean "demanded"; it is closer to "(strongly) hoped for" or "anticipated".

Answer (score 7):

"Expect" means "anticipate", to believe that something is going to happen or is likely to happen.

It is sometimes used to mean "hope" or "wish", like a parent may tell a child, "I expect you to behave yourself at school today", meaning that the parent hopes the child will behave or is commanding the child to behave. This is, I think, a derived meaning from "anticipate". You are saying, "This is what I want you to do, and I just take it for granted that you will do it, right? You ARE going to do what I ask, aren't you?"

As BarrieEngland says, "the coast" here is a personification of an inanimate object. I don't suppose that "the coast" has any thoughts about the weather, it is people who have thoughts about what the weather on the coast will be.

Answer (score 3):

It means that it is very likely that there will be thunderstorms along the coast. This is a figurative use of langauge in which the coast is imagined as being person, and thus capable of having expectations.