# "What is expecting you" as not a question

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I'm going to print a poster for my colleagues co-workerswith two pictures on it. The first picture will go with caption "*What you are expecting*" and the second with "*What is expecting you*". However I'm not sure whether "*what is expecting you*" is good on the place, it looks like a question for me.

Is it okay or is it better to write "What you expect" and "What expects you"?

Context:  It's about what you will see arriving to a certain place. For example, going to a beach you hope to see there sun and blue sea ("what you are expecting"-part) but coming to the place you see rain and wind ("what is expecting you"-part).

Comment: It's OK, the variant with the present continuous is better in my (NNS) opinion. **What** = **the thing which** here.

Comment: *What is expecting you?* is syntactically valid, but idiomatically unlikely because the act of "expecting" someone (awaiting their arrival) is normally only something a ***person*** might do (so it would usually be ***Who** is expecting you?).

Comment: ...I think maybe the concept you're trying to express is ***What is expected of you?*** Compare *Ask not what your country can do for you. Ask what **you** can do for your country.* Also *England expects every man to do his duty*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I don't understand your objection. I'm NNS, but the meaning seems quite clear to me: "What you are expecting" = _What you are dreaming of._  Reality: _"What is expecting you"_ is not so bright.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What would be a better verb than "to expect"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers   And your "rule" that _"the act of "expecting" someone (awaiting their arrival) is normally only something a person might do"_ [appears ungrounded.](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&ei=QrwJWsSIL4Tp6ASs5LugDA&q=%22is+expecting+you%22&oq=%22is+expecting+you%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l2.7874.9034.0.10619.2.2.0.0.0.0.105.204.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.203...0j0i7i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.dezo91qNs2Q) - there is a lot of examples where **something** is expecting you: A New Life Is Expecting You, This is what is expecting you once you arrive.

Comment: @MvLog - To be fair to FumbleFingers, I had a little trouble understanding the meaning, too, until the matter was explained.

Comment: @Mv Log: Gimmie a break! [*A New Life Is Expecting You*](https://www.amazon.com/New-Life-Expecting-You/dp/1503569845) is just a "deliberately non-idiomatic" catchy book title. Btw - if it were true, that would be *there **are** a lot of examples*, not ***is***. But it's not really true anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My fault ))) Mistook **there is a lot of money** for a paradigm for the plural. But non-idiomaticity of the title is of interest to me—having no resources for such subtleties, I can only believe you as a NS.

Comment: @Mv Log:  See earlier [“The coast can expect thunderstorms”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/), which I suspect is one of several ELL questions covering the issue of whether and how verbs primarily associated with *human* "agents" might be used with an inanimate subject.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in particular see Jay's answer to your linked question.  "The coast" doesn't mean the actual shoreline, since geography can't possibly have an opinion.  Everyone understands it to be shorthand for "the people who leave on/near the coast".

Comment: @Andrew: I think you overstate the case. Consider, for example, [Normal main-sequence stars like the sun can expect to end their lives as white dwarfs.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stars+like+the+sun+can+expect%22) Personally, I find it unlikely that we live on the only such star hosting "conscious" entities, but I certainly don't understand *that* example as meaning "the people who live near sun-like stars".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  As per my answer below, change that to a question.  Do you naturally use "who" or do you use "what" expects to end their lives as white dwarfs?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm just wondering why no English usage textbook mentions such an important issue. Usually the matter of agency revolves around an active\passive option, not specifically an animate\inanimate distinction considering the literal\figurative meaning of a verb.

Comment: MvLog: Compare, for example, 1: *He said he wants sexting to be banned* and 2: *He said sexting wants to be banned*. There will always be "literalists" who say the second version there is unacceptable (on the grounds that things like abstract concepts and activities have no consciousness, and hence cannot "want" anything). But I'm certainly not one of them. You might like to look at [*Your quote is not right as it is, **it looks like it wants to be** (suggested improvement).*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/) That's fine by me, and hasn't been challenged by anyone in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FumbleFingers mentions in his comment, certain actions like "expect" or "welcome" can only be done by people -- however, that doesn't mean other, nonhuman entities can't *figuratively* expect or welcome.  It just means that we *personify* these entities and still use the pronoun "who" when referring to them.

> England expects every man to do his duty.

*Who* expects every man to do his duty?  England does.

> Tahiti welcomes you to Tropical Paradise!

*Who* welcomes you?  Tahiti does.

Again, this use is figurative.  It's as if these inanimate objects are people, who can do things normally reserved for humans.  But what about something like:

> The system expects the user to input a five-digit password.

Again, if I had to pick a pronoun, I'd go with "who":

> **Who** expects this of the user?  The system does.

We can argue that "the system" is a thing and I should say *what* not *who*, but "*What* expects this of the user?" doesn't sound quite natural.

A better way to do what you want is to contrast *expectation* vs. *reality*.  Example:

> ***Getting a computer science degree:***
>
> **What you expect**:  Long hours spent hacking up a killer app that you eventually sell for a billion dollars.
>   **What you (actually) get**:  Meetings.  Lots of meetings.

Or this meme:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be too categorical on the issue—I suppose it depends: sometimes **who** goes, sometimes **what** does. I can't imagine e.g. _**Who** expects you—heaven  or hell?_ or _**Who** expects you in the future—happiness or demise—doesn't really matter._ I'd prefer **what** in both cases. Moreover, for my NNS ear **who** is misleading—I literally begin searching for a person here—What person? Whence person?

Comment: @MvLog  It depends if you want to speak "natural" English, or just communicate in whatever way works.  There are hundreds of grammatical ways to figuratively pound a square peg in a round hole, and then spend perhaps minutes or hours explaining what you mean ... but perhaps a better option is to use the patterns which native English speakers use and recognize?

Comment: @MvLog - I definitely prefer "**Who** expects you—heaven or hell?" over "What expects you—heaven or hell?" and I think Andrew's answer here explains why: When using a verb of cognition such as _expects_ or _wonders_ or _thinks_, I expect _**whos**_ to expect and wonder and think about things, not _whats_.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you, that's important information I've never come across before.

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about "expect - get". It will work, thank you!